# JSON Encode NSObject NOT struct?

Tags: json, swift, nsobject

I have an NSObject class

```
class InventPricing: NSObject {  
    var quantity:  NSNumber = NSNumber(value: 00.00)
    var cost:      NSNumber = NSNumber(value: 00.00)
    var total:     NSNumber = NSNumber(value: 00.00)
}
```

Which is kept as an array

```
let prices = [InventPricing]()
```

Trying to Encode the array as a JSON String

```
 print("Insert Inv   List 1                \(prices)   ")
 let encoder = JSONEncoder()
 encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
 let info = try! encoder.encode(prices)
 print("Insert Inv   List 1                \(info  )   ")
 let str  = String(data: info, encoding: .utf8)!
 print("Insert Inv   List 1                \(str   )   ")
```

Getting Error on the   encoder.encode(prices)   line

fatal error: Array does not conform to Encodable because InventPricing does not conform to Encodable.:

All I can find is Encoding a struct not an NSObject Class

Please help!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47531466/6822622). [NSObject] convet to string or data

Answer (score 1):

The process is actually the same for classes and structs, The current pattern is to use structs for the data model though…

You just need to conform to the protocol:

```
class InventPricing: NSObject, Encodable {  …
```

If you want to convert both ways:

```
class InventPricing: NSObject, Codable {  …
```

For more info check out [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types). It uses structs in all the examples but it never says it only works on structs and uses the term 'type' which can be a struct or class.

Comment: Thanks I did as the documentation  showed  now I get Could not cast value of type 'Foundation.JSONEncoder' (0x101863830) to 'Swift.Encoder' (0x109711298).
2017-09-26 15:13:10.188008-0400 EEDS4[7129:3964368] Could not cast value of type 'Foundation.JSONEncoder' (0x101863830) to 'Swift.Encoder' (0x109711298).